# Confused by a proof in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (metric spaces).

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

As the title suggests, I am working on the following problem for which I know the solution:

[image]

I do not understand why the approach used says that we must consider *every* non-empty open subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$. By the exercise, must we only show that $\mathbb{R}^k$ contains some countable, dense subset?

**My approach**: We have that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and that $\mathbb{Q}$ is both countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$. If we show that $\mathbb{Q}^k\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is both dense and countable, are we done? I have written a proof by induction for this which I find much cleaner, but am concerned that my underlying logic is still wrong.

Comment: What is your definition of dense?

Comment: If there were an open subset which did not contain a rational point, the rational points would not be dense.

Comment: You can, if you want, avoid induction on $k$. For example, let $<^*$ be a well-order on $\mathbb Q $. For $r >0$ and $x=(x_i)_{i=1}^k\in \mathbb R^k.$  For each $i$ let $q_i$ be the $<^*$-least member of $\mathbb Q\cap (-r/k+x_i,r/k+x_i).$ Then $(q_i)_{i=1}^k\in \mathbb Q^k\cap B(x,r)$.... So $\mathbb Q^k$ has non-empty intersection with every non-empty open ball of $\mathbb R^k$. Since the set of open balls is a base for the topology on $\mathbb R^k,$ therefore $\mathbb Q^k$ is dense...."Well-order everything in sight."--Mary Ellen Rudin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your approach is correct. Eventually, you will have to give a similar argument like the one in the solution of the book anyway.

The countability of $\Bbb Q^k$ is trivial. To prove that $\Bbb Q^k$ is dense in $\Bbb R^k,$ take any point $x\in \Bbb R^k.$ We build a sequence in $\Bbb Q^k$ convergent to $x.$ For $n\in \Bbb N,$ consider the ball $B(x,\frac{1}{n}).$ Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R,$ for $i=1,...,k,$ we can choose $x_i^n\in \Bbb Q$ such that $$|x_i^n- x_i|\leq \frac{1}{n}.$$ Now the point $x^n=(x_1^n,\ldots,x_k^n)$ satisfies

$$x^n\in \Bbb Q^k\cap B(x,\frac{1}{n}).$$ It is easy to see that $x^n\to x,$ as desired.